# Is there any to play with file pointer (as if it is a line number ) to replace strings in prev line(s) based on the current line reading in python?

Tags: python, file, io

I have a file as below
input_file.txt

123
skj
dsj
aaa
aab
aac
aad
aae
dlk
dls
dsl
...
...
...

As we can see while going through the file line by line, there is some sequence starting from 'aaa' to 'aae' (making the length of 5 ) , I want to insert a command just before 'aaa' 005 (kind of opcode) ,by tweaking the file pointer as line number by going back to that position and return back to current position (file pointer) . I saw tell() and seek()  functions are there in python but they play with cursor positions. Can someone provide me an optimized way to do it.

One way I can think of is put everything in the list and update the list accordingly.

Comment: ",by tweaking the file pointer as line number by going back to that position and return back to current position (file pointer)" I'm sorry, but I do not really understand this.

Comment: By that what I mean is ,I am  reading a file (which contains some opcodes instructions )  line by line  ,and subsequently writing to the other file based on the opcode  , now I am getting a JUMP instruction to go back to nth opcode (which was read already)  and update it  and come again to the current pointer ? Is it possible  ?